# Display list of Trigger sends email names on landing page

Tags: trigger, marketing-cloud, ampscript, landing-page

Edited :
I want to display the names of all the trigger send emails present in the account on landing page. A user should be able to select the one name from this list (Like dropdownlist). Is it possible to achieve this using Amp-script or SSJS or any other method.

Comment: I have an answer for this question.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs...would you like to share the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a [RetrieveRequest](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/retrieverequest/) on the [TriggeredSendDefinition](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/triggeredsenddefinition/) object and output the results however you'd like.

This sample code just retrieves one TSD by CustomerKey, but you could remove the filter and then loop through all of the results with a few adjustments:

```
%%[

var @ret, @filter, @status, @rr

Set @ret = CreateObject("RetrieveRequest")
SetObjectProperty(@ret,"ObjectType","TriggeredSendDefinition")
AddObjectArrayItem(@ret,"Properties","Name")

Set @filter = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
SetObjectProperty(@filter,"Property","CustomerKey")
SetObjectProperty(@filter,"SimpleOperator","equals")
AddObjectArrayItem(@filter,"Value","TSDCUSTOMERKEY")

SetObjectProperty(@ret,"Filter",@filter)

Set @rr = InvokeRetrieve(@ret, @status)

IF rowcount(@rr) > 0 THEN
      Set @row = row(@rr, 1)
      Set @TSDName = field(@row,"Name")
      OutputLine(concat("TSDName: ",@TSDName))
EndIf

]%%
```